# PUT request won't get ID of the record in Vue.js with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to make a CRUD project using Vue.js in Laravel, and I'm successfully in the last step, editing. But I'm stuck in it. 
I'm trying to use the same form to edit that I've use for creating also. One form, two tasks.
 The only error I get is **PUT http://localhost:8000/api/student/undefined 404 (Not Found)**, yeah I can't pass the ID (or model?) to Axios.

I think my routes, controllers in Laravel side are alright, but I can't pass the current ID of the edited record to Axios. Also, I don't have any ID input on the form. That might be the cause.

**My Vue code to edit**

```
addStudent(student, id) {
                if(this.edit === false){
                    axios.post(`api/students/create`, {
                    first_name:this.first_name,
                    last_name:this.last_name,
                    student_number:this.student_number,
                    phone_number:this.phone_number,
                    email:this.email,
                    birth_date:this.birth_date,
                    school_name:this.school_name,
                    });
                } else {
                    axios.put(`api/student/`+this.id, {
                        first_name:this.first_name,
                        last_name:this.last_name,
                        student_number:this.student_number,
                        phone_number:this.phone_number,
                        email:this.email,
                        birth_date:this.birth_date,
                        school_name:this.school_name,
                    });
                }
            },
```

**My route (in api.php)**

```
Route::put('student/{id}', 'StudentController@update');
```

**My Controller**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $student = Student::findOrFail($id);

        $student->first_name = $request->get('first_name');
        $student->last_name = $request->get('last_name');
        $student->student_number = $request->get('student_number');
        $student->phone_number = $request->get('phone_number');
        $student->first_name = $request->get('email');
        $student->email = $request->get('first_name');
        $student->birth_date = $request->get('birth_date');
        $student->school_name = $request->get('school_name');

        $student->save;

        return redirect('/');
```

**Form action**

```
<form @submit.prevent="addStudent()">
```

I need to finish this, I need any help that I can get. Thank you

Comment: `student/undefined ` error this make sure `this.id` not `undefined`

Comment: student/undefined mean there no variable for id. Can you show the code for edit?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesnt understand PUT request, it send it as a put request but without a body (you can only use it like a get method structure). To counter this issue, you need to send it as a POST request with a field `_method = put` for laravel to consider it as a put call

```
addStudent(student) {
                if(this.edit === false){
                    axios.post(`api/students/create`, {
                    first_name:this.first_name,
                    last_name:this.last_name,
                    student_number:this.student_number,
                    phone_number:this.phone_number,
                    email:this.email,
                    birth_date:this.birth_date,
                    school_name:this.school_name,
                    });
                } else {
                    axios.post(`api/student/`+this.id, {
                        _method:'PUT',
                        first_name:this.first_name,
                        last_name:this.last_name,
                        student_number:this.student_number,
                        phone_number:this.phone_number,
                        email:this.email,
                        birth_date:this.birth_date,
                        school_name:this.school_name,
                    });
                }
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `this` and `id` is local vairable

```js
  axios.put(`api/student/`+id, {
                        first_name:this.first_name,
                        last_name:this.last_name,
                        student_number:this.student_number,
                        phone_number:this.phone_number,
                        email:this.email,
                        birth_date:this.birth_date,
                        school_name:this.school_name,
                    });
```

> **Note :**   and you getting 404 error becouse your r using `findOrFail()`

Comment: I still get `student/undefined ` error. Is there a wrong thing while I pass the ID to method?

Comment: Can you give me info on passing the ID? Its so easy in laravel but I'm so new to Vue

Comment: ` <form @submit.prevent="addStudent()">` is where I call `addStudent()`

Comment: I also have edit button that fills the form values. I think I should pass the ID on that, but is there a way that I can pass it from another method?

Comment: @hxk1r your not passing anything u r getting old data right .? from api .? get id from that and when you r updating put thta